# Keras: Chance-level performance

Tags: python-2.7, keras, mnist

I have been trying to train a large neural net, and the losses have not been falling. So I thought of trying out a small `ConvNet` on the MNIST database, since it already exists in `Keras`, and some neutral nets classify it brilliantly.

This is the program I wrote for the job:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras import losses
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import plot_model

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=3)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=3)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

print('Creating model graph!\n')
plot_model(model, to_file='mnist-convnet.pdf', show_shapes=True)
print('Created model graph!\n')

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=50,batch_size=500,shuffle=True,validation_split=0.2,verbose=1)

model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,batch_size=1000,verbose=1)
```

I added the 4th dimension to the `x_train` and `x_test` data so that I could use the `Conv2D` layer. The effective shape of the neural net is:

[image: ConvNet for MNIST image classification]

The problem is that the losses are not falling, and the accuracy is constantly chance-level. Stopped the program in the 7th epoch, because the losses were not falling at all. Here is the performance in the 7th epoch:

```
Epoch 7/50

  500/48000 [..............................] - ETA: 2706s - loss: 14.2484 - acc: 0.1160
 1000/48000 [..............................] - ETA: 2474s - loss: 14.3612 - acc: 0.1090
 1500/48000 [..............................] - ETA: 2341s - loss: 14.4418 - acc: 0.1040
 2000/48000 [>.............................] - ETA: 2391s - loss: 14.5385 - acc: 0.0980
 2500/48000 [>.............................] - ETA: 2357s - loss: 14.5643 - acc: 0.0964
 3000/48000 [>.............................] - ETA: 2350s - loss: 14.5492 - acc: 0.0973
 3500/48000 [=>............................] - ETA: 2275s - loss: 14.5938 - acc: 0.0946
 4000/48000 [=>............................] - ETA: 2259s - loss: 14.5828 - acc: 0.0952
 4500/48000 [=>............................] - ETA: 2222s - loss: 14.5457 - acc: 0.0976
 5000/48000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2189s - loss: 14.5482 - acc: 0.0974
 5500/48000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2225s - loss: 14.5414 - acc: 0.0978
 6000/48000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2303s - loss: 14.5385 - acc: 0.0980
 6500/48000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2263s - loss: 14.5261 - acc: 0.0988
 7000/48000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2229s - loss: 14.5224 - acc: 0.0990
 7500/48000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2231s - loss: 14.5342 - acc: 0.0983
 8000/48000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2212s - loss: 14.5163 - acc: 0.0994
 8500/48000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2196s - loss: 14.5195 - acc: 0.0992
 9000/48000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2146s - loss: 14.5457 - acc: 0.0976
 9500/48000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2106s - loss: 14.5555 - acc: 0.0969
10000/48000 [=====>........................] - ETA: 2051s - loss: 14.5417 - acc: 0.0978
10500/48000 [=====>........................] - ETA: 2031s - loss: 14.5539 - acc: 0.0970
11000/48000 [=====>........................] - ETA: 1987s - loss: 14.5561 - acc: 0.0969
11500/48000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 1949s - loss: 14.5497 - acc: 0.0973
12000/48000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 1927s - loss: 14.5479 - acc: 0.0974
12500/48000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 1892s - loss: 14.5450 - acc: 0.0976
13000/48000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1851s - loss: 14.5373 - acc: 0.0981
13500/48000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1817s - loss: 14.5349 - acc: 0.0982
14000/48000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1800s - loss: 14.5431 - acc: 0.0977
14500/48000 [========>.....................] - ETA: 1771s - loss: 14.5363 - acc: 0.0981
15000/48000 [========>.....................] - ETA: 1757s - loss: 14.5224 - acc: 0.0990
15500/48000 [========>.....................] - ETA: 1728s - loss: 14.5343 - acc: 0.0983
16000/48000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 1704s - loss: 14.5274 - acc: 0.0987
16500/48000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 1666s - loss: 14.5278 - acc: 0.0987
17000/48000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 1603s - loss: 14.5243 - acc: 0.0989
17500/48000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 1543s - loss: 14.5219 - acc: 0.0990
18000/48000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 1486s - loss: 14.5215 - acc: 0.0991
18500/48000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 1431s - loss: 14.5115 - acc: 0.0997
19000/48000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 1379s - loss: 14.4986 - acc: 0.1005
19500/48000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1330s - loss: 14.4848 - acc: 0.1013
20000/48000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1283s - loss: 14.4845 - acc: 0.1013
20500/48000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1238s - loss: 14.4803 - acc: 0.1016
21000/48000 [============>.................] - ETA: 1194s - loss: 14.4694 - acc: 0.1023
21500/48000 [============>.................] - ETA: 1152s - loss: 14.4725 - acc: 0.1021
22000/48000 [============>.................] - ETA: 1112s - loss: 14.4814 - acc: 0.1015
22500/48000 [=============>................] - ETA: 1074s - loss: 14.4798 - acc: 0.1016
23000/48000 [=============>................] - ETA: 1037s - loss: 14.4684 - acc: 0.1023
23500/48000 [=============>................] - ETA: 1000s - loss: 14.4706 - acc: 0.1022
24000/48000 [==============>...............] - ETA: 966s - loss: 14.4720 - acc: 0.1021 
24500/48000 [==============>...............] - ETA: 933s - loss: 14.4727 - acc: 0.1021
25000/48000 [==============>...............] - ETA: 927s - loss: 14.4695 - acc: 0.1023
25500/48000 [==============>...............] - ETA: 918s - loss: 14.4702 - acc: 0.1022
26000/48000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 902s - loss: 14.4678 - acc: 0.1024
26500/48000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 885s - loss: 14.4655 - acc: 0.1025
27000/48000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 875s - loss: 14.4609 - acc: 0.1028
27500/48000 [================>.............] - ETA: 843s - loss: 14.4541 - acc: 0.1032
28000/48000 [================>.............] - ETA: 812s - loss: 14.4631 - acc: 0.1027
28500/48000 [================>.............] - ETA: 782s - loss: 14.4655 - acc: 0.1025
29000/48000 [=================>............] - ETA: 753s - loss: 14.4674 - acc: 0.1024
29500/48000 [=================>............] - ETA: 725s - loss: 14.4686 - acc: 0.1023
30000/48000 [=================>............] - ETA: 697s - loss: 14.4697 - acc: 0.1023
30500/48000 [==================>...........] - ETA: 670s - loss: 14.4698 - acc: 0.1023
31000/48000 [==================>...........] - ETA: 644s - loss: 14.4720 - acc: 0.1021
31500/48000 [==================>...........] - ETA: 619s - loss: 14.4751 - acc: 0.1019
32000/48000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 594s - loss: 14.4791 - acc: 0.1017
32500/48000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 569s - loss: 14.4745 - acc: 0.1020
33000/48000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 545s - loss: 14.4755 - acc: 0.1019
33500/48000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 522s - loss: 14.4779 - acc: 0.1018
34000/48000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 499s - loss: 14.4764 - acc: 0.1019
34500/48000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 477s - loss: 14.4792 - acc: 0.1017
35000/48000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 455s - loss: 14.4805 - acc: 0.1016
35500/48000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 433s - loss: 14.4808 - acc: 0.1016
36000/48000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 412s - loss: 14.4727 - acc: 0.1021
36500/48000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 391s - loss: 14.4736 - acc: 0.1020
37000/48000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 371s - loss: 14.4697 - acc: 0.1023
37500/48000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 351s - loss: 14.4672 - acc: 0.1024
38000/48000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 332s - loss: 14.4651 - acc: 0.1026
38500/48000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 312s - loss: 14.4678 - acc: 0.1024
39000/48000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 294s - loss: 14.4707 - acc: 0.1022
39500/48000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 275s - loss: 14.4720 - acc: 0.1021
40000/48000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 257s - loss: 14.4720 - acc: 0.1021
40500/48000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 239s - loss: 14.4756 - acc: 0.1019
41000/48000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 221s - loss: 14.4689 - acc: 0.1023
41500/48000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 204s - loss: 14.4674 - acc: 0.1024
42000/48000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 187s - loss: 14.4644 - acc: 0.1026
42500/48000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 170s - loss: 14.4642 - acc: 0.1026
43000/48000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 153s - loss: 14.4609 - acc: 0.1028
43500/48000 [==========================>...] - ETA: 137s - loss: 14.4600 - acc: 0.1029
44000/48000 [==========================>...] - ETA: 121s - loss: 14.4605 - acc: 0.1028
44500/48000 [==========================>...] - ETA: 105s - loss: 14.4588 - acc: 0.1029
45000/48000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 89s - loss: 14.4590 - acc: 0.1029 
45500/48000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 74s - loss: 14.4592 - acc: 0.1029
46000/48000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 59s - loss: 14.4537 - acc: 0.1033
46500/48000 [============================>.] - ETA: 44s - loss: 14.4539 - acc: 0.1032
47000/48000 [============================>.] - ETA: 29s - loss: 14.4514 - acc: 0.1034
47500/48000 [============================>.] - ETA: 14s - loss: 14.4516 - acc: 0.1034
48000/48000 [==============================] - 1424s - loss: 14.4499 - acc: 0.1035 - val_loss: 14.3760 - val_acc: 0.1081
```

I do not know why this is happening! What should I do to make the losses fall?

Comment: turn down the batch size, 500 is way to big

Comment: maybe follow the same data processing used in the [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py)

Comment: I tried reducing the `batch_size` to 50, changed the `Conv2D` to `(3,3)` from `(2,2)` and in a second version of the same code, reduced the LR from 0.001 to 0.00005. None of those seemed to work.
As of the `example`, instead of `reshape`, I used `expand_dims`; I do not know whether that should affect the running of the program, because the data is in a `np` array, and `expand_dims` is a `np` function. I do not know why exactly they divided the array values by 225, though.

Comment: ^Changing the Learning Rate from 0.001 to 0.00005 actually worked. I had made some error in calling the modified `RMSprop` properly. I kept the data processing I used.